# How do I make my custom flower spawn in?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I am using this free addon maker (it is pretty bad) and I am trying to my flower spawn in. However, as far as I travel, I never see one. Here is the file:

```
{
  "format_version": "1.13.0",
  "minecraft:feature_rules": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "overworld_underground_sepular_flower_feature",
      "places_feature": "pa_sepular_flower_feature"
  

      },
        "conditions": {
          "placement_pass": "surface_pass",
          "minecraft:biome_filter": [
            {
              "any_of": [
                {
                  "test": "has_biome_tag",
                  "operator": "==",
                  "value": "flower_forest"
                },
                {
                  "test": "has_biome_tag",
                  "operator": "==",
                  "value": "plains"
                },
                {
                  "test": "has_biome_tag",
                  "operator": "==",
                  "value": "bee_habitat"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "distribution": {
          "iterations": 1,
          "coordinate_eval_order": "zyx",
          "x": 0,
          "y": "query.heightmap(variable.worldx, variable.worldz) + 1",
          "z": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Please note my addon creator only allows the block to spawn on one type of block using the block filter, which won't work.

Comment: I highly doubt anyone's going to download that (sorry) but a better option would be to add the directory (i.e. `BehaviorPack/functions/myFunction.mcfunction`) and then add the contents of the file. Do this for the relevant file or files. Exactly like your other question but preferably add the directory so that I can verify it's in the right folder with the right name!

Comment: Thanks! I updated it!

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood. Put the contents of the relevant file in the question along with its directory. That will make it super easy for anyone who knows to be able to answer and I bet you'd get a good answer if you do! (No guarantees tho)

Comment: Also you may want to change what program you are using. Because also considering your last question, and as you said, it does seem that this one is sort of bad. [bridge.](https://github.com/bridge-core/bridge./releases/tag/v1.7.18) while slightly complicated is a great one, but I'm sure you could find other ones that are slightly simpler and that work better than yours there.

Comment: I don't know what you meanv the files are attached

Comment: im gonna bounty this for all my rep cause idc

Comment: I mean you should put the *contents* of the file in the question itself

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what kind of answer you're expecting if you don't know how to do that. What would your ideal answer even look like?

Comment: how to fix it .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124641/discussion-between-penguin-and-anthony).

Comment: Penguin please add an answer i wanna give u the bounty

Answer (score 0):

You may have made a very rare object. It can only appear 1/256 of the time and only 2 tiles above one of the 256 surface tiles in each 16x16 chunk.

Try changing the 'distribution' to make your object more common. I've changed the following:

- The `iterations` variable controls how often a thing spawns.
- Setting the `x` and `z` coordinates to a distribution should allow the feature to spawn on more blocks in the chunk.
- The `query.heightmap()` function already returns a `y` coordinate one above the landscape, so I've removed the '+1' (unless you want a hovering flower, then change it back).

The result of that is:

```
     "distribution": {
      "iterations": 10,
      "coordinate_eval_order": "xzy",
      "x": {
        "distribution": "uniform",
        "extent": [ 0, 16 ]
      },
      "y": "query.heightmap(variable.worldx, variable.worldz)",
      "z": {
        "distribution": "uniform",
        "extent": [ 0, 16 ]
      }
    }
```

See if this makes your object spawn more often.

---

You can use these **resources** to guide you further:

- Guide to custom block distribution (this one's in Japanese): https://tokamcwin10.blog.jp/article-41591212
- General bedrock modding features: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_features_documentation
- JSON schema for custom biomes: https://rinca-h.github.io/minecraft/other/biomeschema.html
- Guide to custom biome generation: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/guide/custom-generation
- Guide to moLang (used in various expressions in such files): https://bedrock.dev/docs/stable/MoLang

Comment: Thank you! However, this did not work

Comment: it didnt work..